# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "04-02-2019"

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat, parseexception

**First of all , i know there are lots of questions regarding my same problem.But that was not enough to solve my problem.So if anyone can provide anything then it would be great.**
In my term the date comes as string format first and after that i need to convert it into date.But i was not able to do that.

I want the format as the format string has .Like as date should be as like as  04-02-2019.

**Here is my java code:**

```
    Date date=null;
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    try {
        date=dateFormat.parse(paymentDate);
        Log.v("Date:",""+date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note : paymentDate="04-02-2019"
**Exception:**

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "04-02-2019"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:362)
```

Comment: Try with: `SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");`

Comment: Thanks.But putting 3M(MMM) was causing the problem?

Comment: My bad.I will check the docs.

Comment: @SakhawatHossain commonly to change a date format from `04-02-2019` to `04 Feb 2019` then you need to read in the date and then reformat it.  It cannot read it in and reformat at the same time.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Important: In the code in the question please don’t fix the error you asked about. When you do, the question will no longer make any sense, and cannot be useful for future readers. With the error in the code it’s a fine question, and chances are great that others will learn from it (and the answer and the comments) and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format `dd-MMM-yyyy` means date in format 04 Feb 2019 // 25 Mar 1993 etc.

Replace it with `dd-MM-yyyy`

Please have a look once again at your complied files. It should work.

Here is the code running as online snippet:

[image]

Comment: Still not the format i want.Your format gave me this (Thu Feb 07 00:00:00 GMT+06:00 2019).May be there is something wrong that i am not able to catch up.

Comment: Could you please update the question so we can run the code snippet?

Comment: Could you add also initializatio for paymentDate?

Comment: paymentDate has the value as paymentDate="04-02-2019"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I followed your code too , but i am getting date=Mon Feb 04 00:00:00 GMT+06:00 2019 . I used the exact same code as yours.

Comment: I think the parse method that i am calling was not able to parse the date.It just kept the format as default for date.